# XCode Convert SQL Blob to .txt file or Read contents

Tags: xcode, text-files, blob

I'm working on a iOS application that access data from SQL Server through an XML service running on the server.  Within this database, there's a textile BLOB field that I need to get and save in a temporary folder.  I have searched high and low for a solution on the internet without any luck.  I'm new to Objective-C programing and don't have all the tools as of yet. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Hamid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...I found the answer to this.

```
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:myData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
[myString writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

myData is NSData filled with Blob
filePath is sandbox save location.